# find out which class is missing

Tags: centos, java

I was trying to install liquibase on my CentOS 6.9 it needs java (i have `openjdk version "1.8.0_121"`) but i got this error:

```
  [root@sampleliquibase-3.6.2-bin..z]# ll
  total 11412
  drwxrwxrwx. 2 db2inst1 db2iadm1    4096 Dec 17 13:10 lib
 -rwxrwxrwx. 1 db2inst1 db2iadm1   11358 Jul  3 23:27 LICENSE.txt
 -rwxrwxrwx. 1 db2inst1 db2iadm1    1251 Jul  3 23:27 liquibase
 -rwxrwxrwx. 1 db2inst1 db2iadm1 9406606 Dec 17 09:42 liquibase-3.6.2- 
  bin.zip
 -rwxrwxrwx. 1 db2inst1 db2iadm1     884 Jul  3 23:27 liquibase.bat
 -rwxrwxrwx. 1 db2inst1 db2iadm1 2167086 Jul  3 23:30 liquibase.jar
 -rwxrwxrwx. 1 db2inst1 db2iadm1    7174 Jul  3 23:27 liquibase.spec
 -rwxrwxrwx. 1 db2inst1 db2iadm1    3046 Jul  3 23:27 README.txt
 drwxrwxrwx. 6 db2inst1 db2iadm1    4096 Dec 17 13:10 sdk
 -rwxrwxrwx. 1 root     root       41203 Mar 16  2017 slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar
 [root@sampleliquibase-3.6.2-bin..z]# java -jar liquibase.jar
 Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try 
 again
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
 ch/qos/logback/core/filter/Filter
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at 
    sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
    ch.qos.logback.core.filter.Filter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
    [root@sampleliquibase-3.6.2-bin..z]#
```

I think some kind of class is missing but i dont know which one is and how i can add it to java classes. what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

`ch/qos/logback/core/filter/Filter`

aka

`ch.qos.logback.core.filter.Filter`

is missing which is part of Logback, you can add it to the application using your buildscript. Or manually install it to your lib folder from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-core

Maybe you are launching the wrong file. Instead of running the jar directly you might have to run the "launcher" script instead.